# Cannot allow external connections in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7

I have a server with Postgres installed and I want to allow the connection from external IP's. Postgres works very well for local connections, then at the end of the file `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgressql.conf` I added:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And in the end of `/var/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` I added:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                md5
host    all             all              ::/0                     md5
```

Then I restarted postgres with: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`
And tried to connect with: `psql -h my.db.server.ip -U postgres`

And I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No existe ninguna ruta hasta el «host»
    Is the server running on host "my.db.server.ip  and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am using Centos 7 and PostgreSQL 9.2.23
What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

- Use

  ```
  netstat -an | grep 5432
  ```

  on the server to see if anything is listening on port 5432.
- See what `port` is set to in `postgresql.conf`.
- Use `lsof` on the PostgreSQL server process to see what sockets PostgreSQL is listening on.

Comment: Hello! yes, indeed it was running, the problem was the firewal. I opened the port and finally it worked